# NGINX with proxy_cache as fallback

Tags: nginx, caching, proxy, webserver, fallback

I am trying to use an NGINX as a proxy_cache, via which I route requests to an external service and the responses are to be stored in the cache and are only delivered if the external service cannot be reached.

Case 1: External service is available: NGINX forwards response directly to the client.

Case2: External service is no longer available: NGINX delivers response from cache.

With my current configuration, the response from the external service is routed directly to my client and cached. The second request is then delivered directly from the cache. As a result, updates in the external service are only fetched after the cache has expired.

Is there a way that the cache is only used when the external service cannot be reached?

I am currently using the following configuration:

nginx.conf:

```
http {
proxy_cache_path / mnt / nginx / cache levels = 1: 2 keys_zone = externalservice: 50m max_size = 5g inactive = 60m use_temp_path = off;
}
```

sites-available/externalservice:

```
  location / {
     set $ proxy_target external.service.com;
     proxy_pass https: // $ proxy_target;
     proxy_set_header host external.service.com;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $ proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $ host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $ remote_addr;

     # outbound proxy cache config for external.service.com;
     proxy_cache externalservice;
     proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504; #deliver stale content for origin errors
     proxy_cache_revalidate on; #validate Last-Modified and If-Modified-Since
     proxy_cache_background_update on;
     proxy_cache_lock on; #serve first request and queue in parallel
     proxy_ignore_headers cache control; #force caching as client does not send HTTP cache header
     proxy_cache_valid any 5m;
     add_header X-Cache-Custom $ upstream_cache_status;
  }
```